# Proxy pass to multiple sub domain in apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, http-proxy

In my webserver (Ubuntu 14.04), I have installed Apache 2.4, tomcat 7 and shiny web framework. I want to use Apache 2 to server all my webpages. So I use JKMount to set sub directory `tomcat_demo` for tomcat server, and http_proxy for shiny app. See my configuration below.

```
JKMount /tomcat_demo* worker1
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass "/shiny/" "http://localhost:3838/users/user/app/"
ProxyPassReverse "/shiny/" "http://localhost:3838/users/user/app/"
```

Now I want to change my http_proxy from sub directory shiny into root folder. i.e. `https://my-ip-address/` to directly access `http://localhost:3838/users/user/app/` with this setting.

```
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3838/users/user/app/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:3838/users/user/app/"
```

However, I cannot access `https://my-ip-address/tomcat_demo`. Is it possible to achieve my target above? i.e. Set proxy pass for root folder and sub directory.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the exclamation mark <kbd>!</kbd> you can define an exclude before your ProxyPass rule for  the root.

```
   ProxyPass /tomcat_demo !
   ProxyPass / http://...
   ProxyPassReverse / http://...
```